# How to center my figure without the limitation of text width?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, lncs, textwidth

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=18cm]{3DQN.eps}
    \caption{Performance and instability}
    \label{3DQN}
\end{figure}
```

I'm writing with the LNCS template on Overleaf, and there's a rather wide figure I need to put on (illegible if made narrower). Because the left side is be lined up with the text, the `\centering` command doesn't work anymore, and it turns out to look like the following:
[image: figure]

Is there a way to break the left-lineup and center the figure without changing its width (like where the yellow box is)? Thank you!

Comment: You *could* use `\centerline{\includegraphics[width=18cm]{3DQN.eps}}` but absolutely should not unless you really have explored all other options.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Oh thank you! Haha

Comment: `\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=18cm]{3DQN.eps}}`

Comment: @Werner Thank you so much! It works perfectly!